# Find a common script that is attached to multiple gameObjects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that has been attached to multiple gameObjects and this script I am referencing in another script. However when referred, only one gameObject is accessed instead of accessing all.
How do I access all the gameObjects that use this script?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CheckForGrab : MonoBehaviour {

    private OVRGrabber grabber; //the script I try to access
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        grabber = (OVRGrabber) FindObjectOfType(typeof(OVRGrabber)); // the gameObject the script is attached to
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want multiple results, you have to query for multiple instances. Obviously.

Try [FindObject**s**OfType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html). Note the 's'.

---

Also, use generics instead of casting in this case.

```
grabbers = FindObjectsOfType<OVRGrabber>();
grabber = grabbers[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: FindObjectsOfType(typeof(OVRGrabber) instead FindObjectOfType(typeof(OVRGrabber)

The s is important.

Your code will be this way:

```
private OVRGrabber[] grabbers; 
private OVRGrabber grabber;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    grabbers = (OVRGrabber) FindObjectsOfType(typeof(OVRGrabber)); 

    grabber = grabbers[0]; //iterate if you want to do stuffs with everyone of them

}
```

Comment: Thank you, as mentioned in the other answer, the following line has been replaced to this:

grabbers = (OVRGrabber) FindObjectsOfType(typeof(OVRGrabber)); //from

grabbers = FindObjectsOfType<OVRGrabber>(); //to